# Generic way to return a whole collection

Tags: c++, templates

In C++, what is the best way to return a collection to client code without using iterators.

Let's say iterators are ruled out because eg the collection is remote. I'd like a signature for a function that returns the collection in the most useful form possible.

By 'best', I mean the best trade-off between clarity and genericity.

My instinct was (where result.push_back(obj) is valid C++):

```
template <typename T>
void getCollection(T& result);
```

I wonder if anyone has better ideas, for example that would also support insertions into containers that do not support push_back, or that require transformation of the objects in the collection.

The following, perhaps?

```
template <typename Func>
void getCollection(Func f); // applies f to all the objects
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I really, really, really don't see what problem you're trying to solve. What does push_back have to do with your first option? Why can't you use iterators for a remote collection? The iterator interface seems like a perfect match for that. Your question is so vague I'm wondering why you can't just do `template <typename CollectionType> CollectionType& GetCollection()`. What is it you need?

Comment: There are two things I don't understand from the question: what do you want to achieve? why are iterators not the solution? Can you clarify --I believe that iterators *are* the solution even if I have not quite grasped the question...

Comment: Could you clarify the "remote" part? I don't see any connection.

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer to [one of my questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916279/stlifying-c-classes). The idea of returning an output iterator for inserting into a collection managed by one of my classes would never have occurred to me, but it's pretty slick.

Comment: @shambulator: I realized when clicking on the +1 for this answer... that I had already upvoted it :x

Answer (score 4):

The iterator way is the way you really want.  Why?  Because it allows the client to stick this data into whatever they need to.  As you are aware, you're already having trouble deciding how to stick data on the end of the container because there are different ways.  With an OutputIterator though you don't have to worry about it.  Assign and move forward.

Hell, the user of your function might want to stick the data in a string and if you use the iterator method this is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to better describe your problem.  Simply, to return a collection, I would say, use a template that returns an iterator.  But if you are talking about client code, i.e. the app will be separated into a few parts and they might be compiled separately, I would say the only portable way is to use a pointer to an array.  But, what do you mean by remote?  If it means a seperate machine, then you need some form of serialization like [Boost::Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) or [Protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/).

Answer (score 0):

I think I have finally understood your problem, I'll just rephrase it:

- You have a collection of objects
- You wish your client to have access to the objects, without knowing the details of implementation
- The collection and the client might be on different machines (you thus have a way to put it in a message)

I would simply return a copy of the collection, suitably wrapped to abstract away the actual implementation.

For example, a `Collection` class, with `begin` and `end` members to access custom iterators. The class is instantiated with the serialized form of the collection, and deserialize it (lazily or not). It's up to your client to use the iterators to stash the data in the collection she wishes.

Answer (score -1):

My friedns' favorite way of returning a whole bunch of data from a function is by using shared pointers:

```
boost::shared_ptr<vector<string>>  f()  {
   boost::shared_ptr<vector<string>> vec(new vector<string>());
   vec->push_back(....);
   return vec;
}
```

Comment: Unnecessary, inefficient, and wrong smart pointer.  If you have it, you should be using std::unique_ptr, if not you should be using std::auto_ptr.  Once in a shared_ptr you can never get it out and use it in a more appropriate smart pointer.  You should at least be giving the client the choice.

Comment: I can't agree. One smart pointer is enough for all your programs. Efficiency is needed to this extent in 0.00001% of the cases, and then it will all be handled differently.

Comment: This has nothing to do with efficiency.  If one smart pointer is enough, why do you think the standard is adding 2 of them?  Shared semantics is quite often not what is desired.

Comment: Its not just a question of efficiency, but also of clarity.  By using `shared_ptr`, you are pretending that nobody owns that container when that is clearly not the case.  Now, I'm left wondering what I'm allowed to do with the container, and who else might notice the changes I make.  `unique_ptr` [or, in today's standard `auto_ptr`] make it clear that there's only one instance of this container floating around unless I chose to move it into a `shared_ptr` myself.

Comment: Of course, given that the original question, while vague, seems to suggest ownership of the container isn't being transfered out of the routine, a `shared_ptr` would be appropriate.  Should this method of passing things around be chosen.

Comment: I agree with Noah, it's not a matter of efficiency, it's a matter of semantics. Sharing an object between two parts of the code leads to subtle bugs, thus by default you usually don't share. Why not simply returning a copy ? With RVO and move semantics it's actually cheap.